# How to fix slope calculation in stat_poly_eq?

Tags: r, ggplot2, stringr, ggrepel, ggpmisc

I used stat_poly_eq to display the calculated linear equation on the graph, but the displayed results were very different from the actual ones. The actual slope cannot be greater than 0.5.
Can anyone help me correct this error?
​

Here is my data:

```
df<-structure(list(Variety = c("Sultana - MG 000", "ES Pallador - MG I", 
"Isidor - MG I", "Santana - MG I/II", "Blancas - MG II", "Ecudor - MG II"
), FTSWt2017 = c(0.54, 0.47, 0.41, 0.18, 0.25, 0.18), FTSWt2021 = c(0.32, 
0.27, 0.35, 0.29, 0.22, 0.32)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Here is my code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpmisc)
library(ggrepel)
library(stringr)
library(stats)
ggplot(df, aes(x = FTSWt2017, y = FTSWt2021)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Variety)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = 'y ~ x', se=FALSE,color="black") +
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1, color="gray", 
              linetype="dashed", size=0.5)+
  (
    aes(label = paste(
      gsub(
        '\\.',
        "*paste('.')*",
        str_replace_all(after_stat(eq.label), "\\.([0-9])[0-9]", "\\.\\1")
      ),
      gsub('\\.', ".", after_stat(rr.label)),
      sep = "*plain(\";\")~~"
    )))
```

Here is the output figure:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QGFp.png)

Comment: Well, the issue is that you are removing some of the digits with `str_replace_all`. Perhaps you could clarify what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hello! The real text on the figure should be "y=0.27+0.08x  R2=0.07". I just want the text on the figure to be the correct equation (All numbers are to the consistent two or three decimal places.) for the linear regression simulated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want to round the the displayed coefficients to 2 digits I think the easiest approach would be to set `output.type="numeric"` which will give you access to a `tibble` containing the coefficients which makes it much easier to achieve your desired result instead of manipulating the `plotmath` string:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpmisc)

ggplot(df, aes(x = FTSWt2017, y = FTSWt2021)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Variety)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = "y ~ x", se = FALSE, color = "black") +
  geom_abline(
    intercept = 0, slope = 1, color = "gray",
    linetype = "dashed", size = 0.5
  ) +
  stat_poly_eq(
    aes(label = after_stat(
      paste0(
        "italic(y)~`=`~", round(b_0, 2), "+", round(b_1, 2), "*italic(x)",
        "*`,`~italic(R)^2~`=`~", round(r.squared, 2)
      )
    )),
    output.type = "numeric",
    parse = TRUE
  )
```

[image]